# Python: Masking Named Entities in Email Text

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, text-mining, named-entity-recognition, data-masking

I have created a python script to extract named entities as follows:

```
# set java path
java_path = r'C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/java.exe'

os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

# initialize NER tagger
sn = StanfordNERTagger('C:/Users/Parag/Documents/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                       path_to_jar='C:/Users/Parag/Documents/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar')

# tag named entities
ner_tagged_sentences = [sn.tag(sent.split()) for sent in dataset_unseen['Text']]
```

```
dataset_unseen['Text'] = dataset_unseen.apply(Detectner,axis=1)
```

```
# extract all named entities
named_entities = []

for sentence in ner_tagged_sentences:
    temp_entity_name = ''
    temp_named_entity = None

    for term, tag in sentence:
        if tag != 'O':
            temp_entity_name = ' '.join([temp_entity_name, term]).strip()
            temp_named_entity = (temp_entity_name, tag)

        else:
            if temp_named_entity:
                named_entities.append(temp_named_entity)
                temp_entity_name = ''
                temp_named_entity = None
```

```
entity_frame = pd.DataFrame(named_entities, columns=['Entity Name', 'Entity Type'])
entity_frame.head()
```

** Output **

```
 Entity Name      Entity Type       Frequency

 ABC Farms        ORGANIZATION          5 

 Freddy Hill Lane  ORGANIZATION          3 

 North Lane Thames ORGANIZATION          2
```

Now I want to mask these named entities with a pattern like "######" to follow GDPR regulations by hiding customer sensitive information.

I have attempted options like:

1. Applying for loop on original data frame - check Text for named entities present in named entity data frame - mask named entity with '#####'.
2. Define a function for masking named entities in Text:

```
def Detectner(row):
    ner_tagged_sentences = [sn.tag(sent.split()) for sent in row['Text']]
    results = ner_tagged_sentences.sub('**********',row['Text'])
    return results
```

`dataset_unseen['Text'] = dataset_unseen.apply(Detectner,axis=1)`

*But I get Following Error:*

`AttributeError: ("'list' object has no attribute 'sub'", 'occurred at index 0')`

How can I extract and mask named entities in Text. Any improvement to this code is highly apprciated !

Answer (score 1):

When you make the tagged sentences, you are creating a `list` in the line

```
ner_tagged_sentences = [sn.tag(sent.split()) for sent in row['Text']]
```

The `type` of `ner_tagged_sentences` is `list` which has no `sub` method.

You can try multiple things to achieve your goal to make documents anonymous:

1. Replace tokens with non-`O` tags with something (token-level)
2. Replace Named Entity Text directly in document (string-level)

It seems like you are trying to do number (2)

Comment: please think about accepting the answer if you believe it is correct.

Comment: I am currently replacing named entities in data frame with a pattern like '*****' . Script is able to identify and mask 70% of named entities. I would like to know how can I improve it to maximum ? Any suggestions !

Comment: I am adding column month to data frame by extracting it from Date column. I want to get no of records with relevant tags like 'Person' or 'Organization' (entities with tags other than 'O'). Its giving good results in absence of feature 'Month' but when I am adding 'Month' feature to data frame to get count of records with named entities group by & order by month its giving completely false results. Would you like to suggest any alternative for this !

Comment: One more issues is about execution time required due to for loops. For loop takes 55 minutes for dataset with1000 records. How can we reduce execution time ? Kindly guide me on it!

Comment: Basically, your training data is not like your text input. This is a common problem. Either label with your data and train, or try adding additional features and retrain.

Comment: I didn't get your point completely about labeling & training data. Here, stanford_ner_tagger is identifying named entities with tags like 'Person', 'Organization', 'Other' etc. So what are you referring to by labeling data or adding additional features. Please clarify so I can work on it.

Comment: You need to train with Email texts, the Stanford ner tagger is not trained on texts like yours so it makes errors